# Customize Default Filter in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove some of filter option like "Default Sorting" from my woo commerce product category page.

So from where I can remove

I want to remove "default sorting" and "sort by newness"

From where I can remove this filter options in woocommerce.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in `functions.php` file in your theme, `$args` array has the following keys: `menu_order`, `popularity`, `rating`, `date`, `price`, `price-desc`.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'woocommerce_custom_catalog_orderby' );

function woocommerce_custom_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    unset ( $args['menu_order'] );  
    return $args;
}
```